# How does scrapy-splash filter duplicates?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

When using scrapy-splash library to render JS. We add its custom DUPEFILTER_CLASS to the settings.py file.

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

Seems like this is used to filter requests in order not to send much requests and speed up the process. But, what is the base for filtering requests when using **scrapy-splash**? is it the **url**?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicates are detected using the [splash_request_fingerprint](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/blob/ba6d7473bbad304cd93cdef55061f31ae641e766/scrapy_splash/dupefilter.py#L17) function. From looking at the code and [issue 900](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/900) (still open) , the url is taken into account, but [you have the option](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/900#issuecomment-469007165) of passing a meta parameter to the request if you want to differentiate it from some other request with the same url. But we have to look at [scrapy.utils.request:request_fingerprint](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/request.py#L22) because this too is called.

What **is** part of the fingerprint:

- [the url of the request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/49e8a33/scrapy/utils/request.py#L59)
- [the request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) ([source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/49e8a33/scrapy/utils/request.py#L58) and keep_fragments is set to True)
- [the request's body](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/49e8a33/scrapy/utils/request.py#L60)

What's **not** part of the fingerprint:

- the [http request headers](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/49e8a33/scrapy/utils/request.py#L61) (since include_headers [is None](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/blob/ba6d7473bbad304cd93cdef55061f31ae641e766/scrapy_splash/dupefilter.py#L17) by default)
- [url fragments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) by default are not used to compute the fingerprint, [unless](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/blob/ba6d7473bbad304cd93cdef55061f31ae641e766/scrapy_splash/dupefilter.py#L28) `request.meta.splash.args` contains the key `url`

It's useful to follow [issue 900](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/900) in order to keep up to date. In the [later comments](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/900#issuecomment-469840510) , some recipes and examples for using/customizing fingerprinting are starting to emerge.